# MFMessageComposeViewController - Remove 'Buddy Name'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I'm using the `MFMessageComposeViewController` to allow my users to send out app download invites to their friends. I want to load the `View Controller` with the recipients field blank, so the user can add whoever they wish. When I use the code below, a recipient 'Buddy Name' displays. How can I remove this?

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];   
if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])       
{
    messageController.body = @"My app text...";
    messageController.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil];
    messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:messageController animated:YES completion:nil];        
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This can remove the Buddy Name:

```
messageController.recipients = nil
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the following line

```
messageController.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil];
```

Comment: @C6Silver It doesn’t suggest to add this line, but opposite suggests to remove it

Comment: Apologies, you are correct. I misread your post. I removed my comment.